# AWS - WAF : log configuration for kinesis firehose in cloud formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, aws-cloudformation, amazon-kinesis, web-application-firewall

I'm trying to enable logging for WAF Regional WEBACL using a cloud formation template. However, I do not find any aws documentation in WAF cloudformation to enable LogConfiguration. Is this not supported yet through cloud formation? Could I get some pointers for this scenario?

Comment: Had a support ticket raised with AWS. they confirmed this is not implemented yet in cloud formation.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah still not supported from what I have seen sadly https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/349